# I need to edit html page based on action done in PHP (Email form)

Tags: php, html

This is the HTML email form:

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
                    <h4>E-mail</h4>
                    <div class="border-stripes"><input type="email" class="textfield" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address" /></div>
                    <h4>Message</h4>
                    <div class="border-stripes"><textarea class="textarea" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea></div><br /><br />
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

and this is the php file corresponding to it:

```
if($_POST['submit']){
if(!isset($_REQUEST['email']) || strlen(trim($_REQUEST['email'])) == 0){
    echo '<p>Please provide us with an email</p>';
} else if(!isset($_REQUEST['message']) || strlen(trim($_REQUEST['message'])) == 0){
    echo '<p>Please do not send an empty message</p>';
}else if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $email)){
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');  
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
}
```

As one can see, the actions done are simply echo messages that are generated on a new page. However, what I want to do is edit the html page. For example if the email is invalid I would like to write next to the message section ON THE SAME HTML PAGE that the email is invalid. This code generates a new blank page with a message that the email is invalid.

Comment: change form action to current page - process how you like

Comment: You can do it by jquery validation or form action change to current page and do your stuff

Comment: That's client side validation, you may use jQuery and/or AJAX.

Comment: stop suggesting jquery is the answer to every question

Comment: add `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to your form `action` or keep it empty

Comment: If you want to cross page updates, you have to consider an AJAX call, else its simply not possible. As stated below and up here, your other option is to execute the php on the same page.